# Adding an option to (primefaces) jquery calendar after creation

Tags: javascript, jquery, primefaces, calendar

I'm working within the parameters of Primefaces.  I'm working with legacy code, and have a primefaces calendar that I need modify so that it will only navigate forward 1 month, and backward 1 month.  The problem is, I can't just add the onChangeMonthYear option to the calendar as it is created, because it's a Primefaces tag.  There is legacy code that I have to take into account, so I can't just "do it with jquery instead".

I need to know how to take a jquery component that is on the page, and add an option to it.  Specifically, I have access to the jquery calendar, but can't figure out how to *add* the onChangeMonthYear option to it.  I tried this:

```
$( document ).ready($("#recsForm\\:sideAccordion\\:calendar_inline").datepicker({
                        onChangeMonthYear:  function(year, month, inst) {
                            alert("IT WORKED!!! Month is: "+month); 
                        }
                    });
}
```

and I tried this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
                    $('#recsForm\\:sideAccordion\\:calendar_inline').datepicker('option', 'onChangeMonthYear', 
                            function(year, month, inst) {
                        alert("IT WORKED!!! Month is: "+month); 
                    });
```

But the first overwrites the old calendar with a new one, and the second doesn't appear to do anything.

A little help?  Please forgive me if this question has already been answered elsewhere.  I looked, but didn't find anything that seemed to help... It could be that I'm just not using the correct terminology.

Answer (score 0):

Wow.  I feel foolish.  The best way to solve this was way easier than I thought:

```
<p:calendar id="calendar" 
            mode="inline" 
            maxdate="#{calendarView.maxDate}"
            mindate="#{calendarView.minDate}" />
```

With the corresponding methods in CalendarView.java:

```
public String getMaxDate() {
    String maxDate = "+2m -";
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    int dayOfMonth = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    maxDate = maxDate.concat(String.valueOf(dayOfMonth));
    maxDate = maxDate.concat("d");
    return maxDate;
}

public String getMinDate() {
    String minDate = "-1m -";
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    int dayOfMonth = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    minDate = minDate.concat(String.valueOf(dayOfMonth-1));
    minDate = minDate.concat("d");
    return minDate;
}
```

Well there you have it.  Thanks.